# Function pointer in cython extension type

Tags: python, cython

I am writing a cython module that provides several extension types that use optimized `cdef` functions. Several of these extension types (about 10, each containing about 200 lines of code) have exactly the same structure but don't call the same `cdef` functions. I would like to factorize my module so that only one extension type can handle all the different configurations I need.

To make this clearer, here is a (very silly) example of the structure of the module I'm writing :

```
cdef class A1:

    cdef double x

    def __init__(self, double x):
        self.x = x

    def apply(self):
        self.x = f1(self.x)

cdef class A2:

    cdef double x

    def __init__(self, double x):            
        self.x = x

    def apply(self):
        self.x = f2(self.x)       

cdef double f1(double x):
    return x**1

cdef double f2(double x):
    return x**2

...
```

and the kind of factorized code I would like to obtain :

```
cdef class A:

    cdef int n
    cdef double x

    def __init__(self, double x, int n):
        self.x = x
        self.f = globals()[f'f{n}']

    def apply(self):
        self.x = self.f(self.x)
```

In pure Python, this kind of structure is easy to setup using `globals` or `getattr`, but in cython `cdef` objects are (of course) not accessible from python, so not in `globals()`.

I guess that a `C` implementation of this kind of code would use function pointers but I can't find how to do this inside an cython extension type. Actually the real question is 'is it possible to add a pointer to a cdef function as an instance attribute (in self) ? If not, how can I factorize this kind of code without losing performances (i.e. without changing my cdef functions) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use function pointer, but with a little bit more boilerplate code than in pure python, for example:

```
%%cython

# here all possible functions double->double
cdef double fun1(double x):
    return 2*x

cdef double fun2(double x):
    return x*x;
...

# class A wraps functions of type double->double
ctypedef double(*f_type)(double) 

# boiler-plate code for obtaining the right functor
# uses NULL to signalize an error
cdef f_type functor_from_name(fun_name) except NULL:
    if fun_name == "double":
        return fun1
    elif fun_name == "square":
        return fun2
    else:
        raise Exception("unknown function name '{0}'".format(fun_name)) 


cdef class A:
    cdef f_type fun

    def __init__(self, fun_name ):
        self.fun = functor_from_name(fun_name)

    def apply(self, double x):
        return self.fun(x)
```

I'm not aware of a possibility to get `cdef`-function pointer from the name of the function at run time and I don't think there is one out-of-the-box.

And now it works as advertised:

```
>>> doubler = A("double")
>>> double.apply(3.0)
6.0
>>> squarer = A("square")
>>> squarer.apply(3.0)
9.0
>>> dummy = A("unknown")
Exception: unknown function name 'unknown'
```

Comment: Great ! 500 lines less :) Thanks