# Cython FIFO cache for function result

Tags: python, caching, cython

I need some kind of cache to store the result of a function `f` in Cython for future reuse. A simple FIFO cache policy that discards the least recently computed result when the cache is full will do just fine. I need the cache to be reinitialised every time I call another function from Python which uses the cache and calls `f`. I came up with the following solution using a `std::map` wrapped in an extension type:

```py
# distutils: language = c++

import sys
import time

from libcpp.map cimport map as cppmap
from libcpp.utility cimport pair as cpppair
from libcpp.queue cimport queue as cppqueue
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref

ctypedef cpppair[long, long] mapitem_t
ctypedef cppmap[long, long].iterator mi_t


cdef class Cache_map:
    """Cache container"""
    cdef:
        cppmap[long, long] _cache_data
        cppqueue[long] _order
        long _cachesize
        long _size

    def __init__(self, long cachesize=100):
        self._cachesize = cachesize
        self._size = 0

    cdef mi_t setitem(
            self, mi_t it, long key, long value):
        """Insert key/value pair into cache and return position"""

        if self._size >= self._cachesize:
            self._cache_data.erase(self._order.front())
            self._order.pop()
        else:
            self._size += 1
        self._order.push(key)
        return self._cache_data.insert(it, mapitem_t(key, value))

    @property
    def cache_data(self):
        return self._cache_data


cdef long f(long x):
    """Expensive function"""
    time.sleep(0.01)
    return x**2


cdef long cached_f(long x, Cache_map Cache):
    cdef mi_t search = Cache._cache_data.lower_bound(x)

    if search != Cache._cache_data.end() and x == deref(search).first:
        return deref(search).second
    return deref(Cache.setitem(search, x, f(x))).second


def use_cache():
    # Output container
    cdef list cache_size = []
    cdef list timings = []
    cdef list results = []

    cdef long i, r
    cdef Cache_map Cache = Cache_map(10)  # Initialise cache

    cache_size.append(sys.getsizeof(Cache))
    go = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        # Silly loop using the cache
        for r in range(2):
            results.append(cached_f(i, Cache))
            timings.append(time.time() - go)
            go = time.time()
        cache_size.append(sys.getsizeof(Cache))
        go = time.time()

    return cache_size, timings, results
```

While this works in principle, it has a few drawbacks:

- I have to manually create `cached_f` to wrap `f` (not very reusable)
- I have to pass `Cache` to `cached_f` (unnecessarily expensive???)
- `Cached_map` is explicitly written to cache results from `f` (not very reusable)

I would imagine that this is quite a standard task, so is there a better way?

I tried, for example, to pass a pointer to the Cache to `cached_f` but it seems I cannot create a pointer to an extension type object? The following:

```py
cdef Cache_map Cache = Cache_map(10)
cdef Cache_map *Cache_ptr

Cache_ptr = &Cache
```

throws `cache_map.pyx:66:16: Cannot take address of Python variable 'Cache'`.

Comment: Python objects (even Cython `cdef class`es) are already passed around as pointers internally, so you definitely don't have to try to use it as a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from the software engineering point of view, it is a good idea to have the function (which is a function-pointer/functor in C/cdef-Cython) and its memoization bundled together in an object/class.

My approach would be to write a cdef class (let's call it `FunWithMemoization`) which has a function pointer and a memoization-data-structure for storing known results.

Because the life is too short to write c++-code with Cython, I have written memoization-class in pure c++ (whole code can be found further bellow), which more or less is very similar to your approach (but rather using `unordered_map`) and wrap/use it with Cython:

```
%%cython -+
from libcpp cimport bool
cdef extern from *:
    """
    // see full code bellow
    """
    struct memoization_result:
        long value;
        bool found;

    cppclass memoization:
        memoization()
        void set_value(long, long)
        memoization_result find_value(long key)

ctypedef long(*f_type)(long)
cdef long id_fun(long x):
    return x


cdef class FunWithMemoization:
    cdef memoization mem
    cdef f_type fun
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.fun = id_fun

    cpdef long evaluate(self, long x):
        cdef memoization_result look_up = self.mem.find_value(x)
        if look_up.found:
            return look_up.value
        cdef long val = self.fun(x)
        self.mem.set_value(x, val)
        return val
```

I'have used `id_fun` to default initialize the `fun`-member, but we need further functionality to make `FunWithMemoization` useful, for example:

```
import time
cdef long f(long x):
    """Expensive function"""
    time.sleep(0.01)
    return x**2

def create_f_with_memoization():
    fun = FunWithMemoization()
    fun.fun = f
    return fun
```

There are obviously other approached to create a useful `FunWithMemoization`, one could use `ctypes` to get the addresses of functions or this [receipt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55963980/5769463).

And now:

```
f = create_f_with_memoization()
# first time really calculated:
%timeit -r 1 -n 1 f.evaluate(2)
#10.5 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
# second time - from memoization:
%timeit -r 1 -n 1 f.evaluate(2)
1.4 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

---

Whole code:

```
%%cython -+
from libcpp cimport bool
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include<unordered_map>
    #include <queue>

    struct memoization_result{
       long value;
       bool found;
    };

    class memoization{
    private:
       std::unordered_map<long, long> map;
       std::queue<long> key_order;
       size_t max_size;
    public:
       memoization(): max_size(128){}
       void set_value(long key, long val){
            //assumes key isn't yet in map
            map[key]=val;
            key_order.push(key);
            if(key_order.size()>max_size){
                key_order.pop();
            }
       }
       memoization_result find_value(long key) const{
          auto it = map.find(key);
          if(it==map.cend()){
              return {0, false};
          }
          else{
              return {it->second, true};
          }
       }      
    };
    """
    struct memoization_result:
        long value;
        bool found;

    cppclass memoization:
        memoization()
        void set_value(long, long)
        memoization_result find_value(long key)

ctypedef long(*f_type)(long)
cdef long id_fun(long x):
    return x


cdef class FunWithMemoization:
    cdef memoization mem
    cdef f_type fun
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.fun = id_fun

    cpdef long evaluate(self, long x):
        cdef memoization_result look_up = self.mem.find_value(x)
        if look_up.found:
            return look_up.value
        cdef long val = self.fun(x)
        self.mem.set_value(x, val)
        return val


import time
cdef long f(long x):
    """Expensive function"""
    time.sleep(0.01)
    return x**2

def create_f_with_memoization():
    fun = FunWithMemoization()
    fun.fun = f
    return fun
```

Comment: Nice way to see it. On a first quick look, I am losing the ability to set the maximum cachesize at runtime and the underlying cached data becomes more opaque when I wrap C++ code in this way, but fair enough. Bundling the cache with the cached function seems like a very good idea anyway.

Comment: @JanJoswig see it as a proof of concept and not a ready to use solution: you could add a `cachesize` parameter to `__cinit__` and pass it to `memoization` so the cache size can be changed.

Comment: Yes, thanks you're right. This will work. Have not thought this through.